# Angular js controller scope inheritance

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Which approach is better for controller scope inheritance?

1. Controller Inheritance via `$injector`
2. Via `$controller`

I am having some static functions in base controller which I need in derived controller. Please suggest the best approach.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `$scope` inheritance by applying your base controller to the top most element in your template.

Or, if you are using `controllerAs` syntax, you can extend another controllers from your base controller like so (ES6):

```
class MyController extends BaseController {

}
```

The first approach won't work for isolate scope.
The second is more specific and should be used carefully — you may think of application architecture.